# Android: Many Views that require frequent redraw. Threading approach?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my application I have a number of Views that represent graphical gauges. At the moment the gauges directly represent a set of input data, with `postInvalidate()` being called on a particular gauge View when the data it is observing changes.

What I want to introduce next is a dampened pointer motion to simulate real gauges, plus possibly some other fancy animation features as well. Performing the calculations for the dampened motion and so forth is of course trivial. What requires some thought is the fact that, after a given View has been initially had `invalidate()` called on it following a change in the data model, that View needs to needs to be 'ticked' (that is, invalidated) periodically to allow it to `onDraw()` several times following the initial data change in order to perform the dampened pointer animation, until the point where the pointer stops completely and the View no longer requires the tick.

I can see two main ways of doing this:

1. Each gauge View has its own Thread to periodically call `postInvalidate()`. This thread will eventually self-stop when the pointer movement sequence has come to an end. The result of this is that if you have a screen with a bunch of gauges shown on it, all responding to different data inputs, then at any time any of those Views could be running its own motion Thread. If the screen is showing ten gauges, then at any time you could have anything from zero to ten individual Threads running in those Views.
2. Second approach is to completely remote away this 'tick' from the Views themselves, and perform the `invalidate()` calls all from a single Thread. This single Thread might be placed in the Activity, or defined in some GaugeTick class, or something. It would work by having individuals register themselves with it when they need to start performing some animation after the initial data model change, and can unregister themselves when done. Each time the 'tick' Thread wakes up (let's say it goes to sleep every 100ms for example, so does a very roughly 10Hz tick) it would run through and call `postInvalidate()` on all Views in its observer ArrayList.

I personally like option 1 because, if I'm to think in an MVC pattern sort of way, the dampened motion is an attribute of the View itself, and it's a mechanism that should be an implementation detail inside that View. From a programming point of view, it feels a lot more elegant to just run an individual Thread inside the View. Furthermore, a View's individual Thread can have a specific sleep interval to suit whatever form or speed of animation it is doing.

On the other hand, would an individual Thread in each View potentially clobber the system in terms of performance, even though they're all going to be short-lived and spend most of their time sleeping? Could I be asking for trouble potentially having so many Threads running, which would all require stopping when the Activity is paused / destroyed, or on orientation change? Going for option 2 feels a lot less of a headache in terms of Thread etiquette.

Thanks,

Trev

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to multi-thread at all. If I understand correctly, you want to redraw a View (the gauges) in response to some user input (touch events). Both drawing and user input are handled by the system UI thread. Just add an `invalidate()` to the method in your gauge View that responds to the user input (probably `onTouchEvent()` in your case). The message queue will receive a message shortly thereafter to redraw the gauge.

`onTouchEvent()` should handle `ACTION_MOVE` events if you want real-time responsiveness or `ACTION_UP` if you want it to respond when the user is done.

Barry

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Barry. The issue however isn't regarding responding to events, however; I already have the Views changing in accordance to updates in the data model via a simple observer mechanism. The issue is concerning the 'best' way to periodically `invalidate()` a given View, or many Views, for a short time after a data change event in order to perform a dampening animation.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by a dampening animation.